# How to use array literals spread operator in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

TypeScript seems to not correctly support [array literals spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator).

Array.from example **worked**
`const uniq1 = (list: Iterable<any>): Array<any> => Array.from(new Set<any>(list))`

Array spread example **broken**
`const uniq2 = (list: Iterable<any>): Array<any> => [...new Set<any>(list)]`

The second example return the following error: **Type 'Set' is not an array type.**

Comment: What's `Set`? I think it's your own type which is not iterable and that's why it's not working. Please include more code.

Answer (score 2):

TypeScript doesn't support *spread operator* now, but it will change in future:

https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Roadmap#21

Answer (score 0):

This is a missing feature. Spreads `...` aren't fully implemented yet.